# Creating new AVD

Tags: android

I'm using Ubuntu Lucid Lynx. I've downloaded and unpacked the SDK and now I need to create an AVD. When I launch Android SDK and AVD Manager, I click Virtual devices and then New. I can't select the target, resolution (from the Built-in list) or CPU/ABI. The dropdown menus are disabled.

What should I do? I can't create new AVD.

Answer (score 8):

if you just installed maybe you must restart yours eclipse on linux.

Comment: Surprisingly enough, this is what fixed it for me. Eclipse restarts seem to happen when needed, but maybe not often enough in my case. Thanks for mentioning this case, @user1825425!

Answer (score 5):

Did you install some android platforms? Go to the `AVD manager -> Available Packages -> Android Repository` and download one or more. Also make sure that your SDK path is set if you are using eclipse to start the manager. Go to `Window -> Preferences -> Android` and set the path. If done correctly, you should get a list of possible targets below the path input field.

Comment: I installed SDK Platform Android 2.1, API 7, revision 3.

Comment: No I have all the packages installed, but I can't create an AVD.

Comment: I have installed all from Android Repository, but I can see only samples, Android Compatibility pachage, Documentation for Android SDK, Android SDK tools and Android SDK Platform tools in Intalled packages. So there's no platforms installed though I have selected all and installed.

Btw. I use Netbeans 7.0.1 not Ecplipse.

Comment: I got no personal experience with netbeans, so I can't help there. But It should work standalone via starting the `android` application from the `ANDROID_SDK\tools` directory. So to eliminate the possibility of an netbeans issue, try it this way. Also where did you install the SDK? Did you probably install it with root and execute it as a user now? If thats the case, the sdk might have no permission to write the things it downloads to disk.

Comment: I ran the android-file from  tools-directory, and I have the same issue.

Comment: I reinstalled my laptop with linux mint (which is ubuntu based) two days ago. I'll write down what I do when I install the sdk later. Will post it this evening, maybe theres something we can figure out.

Answer (score 3):

it remains disable only see the below image to create new Avd [image]

click on CreateAVD done now

Comment: Lol, my problem was that I haven't rights to write to the directory where the SDK was located. I fixed it with runnig the android-file with sudo.