# Why does the OK button remain disabled while creating new AVD in my updated adt-bundle?

Tags: android

[image]

I just installed updated adt-bundle for development but the problem is that when I go to create a new AVD, the OK button will not be enabled. What is the problem? Why OK button stays disable? What packages should be installed in SDK manager.

Comment: Did you fill all the **required** fields properly? Can you pleas avoid **CUBITAL BOLD** characters? Tank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7292624/creating-new-avd?rq=1

Comment: upload your screeshot

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to create Android Virtual Device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13488419/unable-to-create-android-virtual-device)

Comment: Please consider accepting the helpful answer below, as per tripleee's reminder on that question. To accept an answer, click the adjacent tick symbol so that it turns green. This is how we reward helpers here on _Stack Overflow_. Downvoted, with regrets.

Answer (score 0):

While creating new AVD you have to fill all compulsory fields with appropriate values.If you entered or selected wrong configuration then it will display error at left side.so make sure that no error is present.. 
Ok button enable only when all configuration are correct

@bhakti here from snapshot it seems CPU/ABI fiels shows No system images installed for this target(API 20),it means that you don't have installed system images for corresponding target.

Android SDK Manager check that you have installed "ARM EABI v7a System Image" (for Android version which you have selected and on you have to install a system image to be able to run a virtual device).

At last you have to restart your eclipse to see installed system images.

Comment: see i uploaded my screenshot. now tell me what is wrong in this?

Comment: you dont have any system image installed,install it from sdk manager

Comment: do you mean "ARM EABI version7a system image"?

Comment: yes you have to install ARM EABI version7a system image for API20

Comment: Check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13488419/unable-to-create-android-virtual-device/13488547#13488547 as PiyushKukadiya and vijay said you are missing the corresponding system image.

Comment: @vijay you should edit your answer explaining system images are missing. Then the OP should validate your answer as the accepted one.